# How to prove the limit point lies in the same subspace?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Given a finite dimensional vector space equipped with a norm-induced metric, let $S$ be a subspace with basis vectors $v_1,..,v_m$. The question is to show if $\{x_k\}\subseteq S$ and $x_k \to x$, then $x$ can be written as a linear combination of $v_1,...,v_m$ and hence $x\in S$. It seems very intuitively true but I have difficulty proving it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let each $x_k=\sum_{i=1}^ma_i^{(k)}v_i$. You know that $\langle\|x_k-x\|:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $0$. Use this to show that each of the $m$ scalar sequences $\langle a_i^{(k)}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is Cauchy and therefore converges to some scalar $a_i$. Then consider the linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^ma_iv_i$.

Comment: great hint! +1..